# How to write roman, super and subscript?

Tags: roman-numerals

I want to print the following in Latex pdf so what should I do:

> alpha <sub>IIb</sub> beta<sup>3</sup>

I have used `$\alpha$_\rmnum{2}_b$\beta$_3`

but the roman number does not come.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. Given what you've done I think you should really start with some basic resources on learning LaTeX.  See [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/2693).

Answer (score 14):

You should make usually only one math environment for all the math code  (only one `$...$`pair), not one for each symbol. On another hand, the use of  `_` (low line character) for subscripts and `^` for superscripts only work *inside* this math environment. For subscripts of more that one character you should group them with `{}` as well as to limit the scope of commands).

Moreover, `\rmnum` is not a standard command in LaTeX, so you should use some package o some macro definition in the preamble to use it, as `\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\romannumeral #1}`. You should always show us a complete document, so people do not have to guess what the hell your code mean.

I am not sure if you need simply "IIb" or the roman number should be in lowercase, or the "b" should be a nested subscript, and if you really need convert Arabic to uppercase roman numerals, that is tricky that  simply write "II", so here there are some variations to start to play:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\alpha_{\romannumeral 2 b}\beta^3$\par
$\alpha_{\textup{\romannumeral 2}_b}\beta^3$\par
$\alpha_{\scriptsize\textup{%
\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral 2}}_b}\beta^3$\par
$\alpha_{{\mathrm II}_b}\beta^3$  
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about having a capital roman number because the script prints like its 2 i's.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, `$` is not like a “shift key” for typing strange characters. An example I saw yesterday on Math.Stackexchange

```
Dim$V/U$ = dim$V-$dim$U$
```

should have been input as

```
$\dim V/U = \dim V - \dim U$
```

(spaces around `=` and `-` are optional).

Second, I looked in the entire tree and found no trace of `\rmnum`. I *guess* it is defined as

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\text{\@Roman{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

The designation “IIb” seems to point to orbitals, so I believe you can simply do like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\mathrm{\@Roman{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\alpha_{\rmnum{2}b}\beta_3$

\end{document}
```

[image]